# Interface for Attributes

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes, aop

An interface is sort of like a contract which when it's implemented within a class you are guaranteed that this class has a set of specific public methods that you can call.

I was wondering how I could use this principle for attributes ; i.e. having a interface which when a class implements it I'm guaranteed that this class has a set of specific attributes.

I am looking for this feature because I am using [Protobuf](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) and this library requires the classes you want to serialize have a specific attribute (`XmlType` for instance, but other similar attributes work too). I would like to manipulate a set of objects whatever their type is as long as they have this specific attribute.

Comment: AFAIK in the current .NET versions there is no such feature. You can relatively easily implement a runtime check, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how you can do that with interfaces.
However, you can do it with an abstract class which has methods with the attributes you want.
These methods will call abstracts methods which then must be implemented.
For example:

```
public abstract class A
{
     [XmlType]
     public void F()
     {
          InnerF();
     }

     protected abstract InnerF();
}

public class B extends A
{
     protected void InnerF()
     {
     }
}
```

Another option ofcourse, is running a post build tool that will validate your code for rules you define.
Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729757/how-to-validate-c-sharp-code)

Comment: I thought about that but that would complexify a lot my model because of how Protobuf works with inheritance (if you're interested, look up the `ProtoInclude` attribute). But if that's the only solution, I'll take it.